# Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I got a index that looks like this.

```
date           close     volume    symbol  
2000-01-01       2        122       A
2000-01-02       3        122       A
...
2000-01-01       199      222       B
2000-01-02       198      123       B
```

And when I try to pivot

```
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns='symbol', values='close')
```

I want a result looking like this:

```
symbol         A   B
date
2000-01-01     2   199
2000-01-02     3   198
```

I dont understand why I get the error. I've followed the karnerl at kaggle and get the same error:
https://www.kaggle.com/dhimananubhav/stock-market-data-analysis-with-python/data

I would like to pivot the volume as well but I think if I start small and understand why I cant pivot this and then I might figure out how to handle the volume as well later.

Using python 3.5.3

Best regard

Comment: Works ok for me

Comment: which version of pandas you using?

Comment: pd version is '0.23.4'

Answer (score 0):

According to pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), this error is raised:

> ...when there are any index, columns combinations with multiple values.